# Get size and uri for all apks in android device(NOT BASE APKS)

Tags: android, apk, size, uri, transfer

**I want to get size and uri for all installed apks in device**.I have already tried as below to get installed apks with size and uris from package manager.

```
            try{
                packages = ArrayList()
                for (packageInfo in requireContext().packageManager.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)) {
                    val appInfo = packageInfo.applicationInfo
                    if (appInfo.flags and ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM != 1) {
                        val appModel = AppModel(appInfo.loadLabel(requireContext().packageManager).toString(),
                                appInfo,
                                packageInfo.versionName,
                                packageInfo.packageName,
                                File(appInfo.publicSourceDir))
                        installedList.add(appModel)
                        if(packageInfo.packageName!=null && packageInfo.packageName!=""){
                            packages.add(packageInfo.packageName)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (ex: Exception){
                ex.printStackTrace()
            }


public AppModel(String friendlyName, ApplicationInfo appInfo, String version, String packageName, File executableFile) {
        this.friendlyName = friendlyName;
        this.fileName = friendlyName + "_" + version + ".apk";
        this.packageName = packageName;
        this.MIME_TYPE = "application/vnd.android.package-archive";
        this.lastModified = executableFile.lastModified();
        this.size = executableFile.length();
        this.uri = Uri.fromFile(executableFile);
        this.uriString = uri.toString();
        this.appInfo = appInfo;
        this.version = version;
        this.shareableFile = new Shareable(AppUtils.getUniqueNumber(), friendlyName, fileName, MIME_TYPE, lastModified, size, uri, true);
        this.shareableFile.packageName = packageName;
    }
```

But it is only giving me the information for base apk and I am not able to install the apk in another device after transferring this base apk. But other apps like Google Files go is able to show full apk size in the apps list. Can you please help me on how can I do that?

Comment: What has executableFile to do with this all?

Comment: exectuable File is actually publicSourceDir of application and I tried fetching size and uri but only able to get base apk

Comment: There is no uri of an apk. You are making one yourself. Makes no sense in this way.

Comment: I am storing the uri of the package's public source directory.It is available for every installed app in the device. I am not making one

Comment: Yes you are making one. There are no uries. You make them with Uri.fromFile(executableFile);

Comment: okay so how can I actually transfer the apk without doing in this way?

Comment: I have no idea what you want.